# Why is resolve dependencies 'classpath' so slow?

Tags: java, gradle

Why do all my gradle tasks become really slow (longer than 5 minutes) when I add apache commons codec and apache commons io dependencies to my project?  To be clear, executing the build task still works, but just takes a very long time. When it is slow, the gradle output is

```
resolving dependencies: 'classpath'
```

Below is the offending portion of my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot"  }
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:0.5.0.M6")
    classpath("org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.11.3")
    classpath("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.37.1")
    classpath("com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1")
    classpath('commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9')
    classpath("commons-io:commons-io:2.4")
  }
}
```

If I do not include the last two classpath dependencies (codec and io), the buildscript is much faster. I am using gradle 1.10 via gradlew.

Comment: Always slow or just the first time?

Comment: I've heard dependency resolution can be slow if the jars are partially in the maven repo and partially in the gradle repo.

Comment: Do you really depend on all this for your build script only?

Comment: @HariShankar it is always slow, not just the first time when it downloads the libraries from Maven

Comment: These dependencies don't belong on the build script class path. And if adding them makes the build always slow, then there is likely some other problem with your build as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question is do you really need to add all those dependencies to the Gradle script's classpath? Are these script plugin dependencies or your application's dependencies?

Your example looks quite different to the Spring Boot [example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/). You are using a much older version of the Spring Boot Gradle plugin.

Comment: Changing my build script to more closely match the Spring Boot example, combined with upping the Spring Boot Gradle plugin version has made it faster. I am not sure why those things helped, but this is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Hari Menon's comment was the right track for me. I had mixed gradle and maven repos, that mad the build terribly sclow using Gradle 3. Removing the gradle repo fixed the issue.